# With Pages '08, can I add a top border to a title?

Tags: macos, pages

I'm writing my resume with Pages, and I'd like to know if (and how) I can add a horizontal line across the page before every text segment with a certain style (namely, "Header", though that shouldn't matter).

Will I necessarily have to draw a straight line myself, and move it around each time a section enlarges?

Comment: Can you post a small screen shot of your layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in Pages '09, so it probably works in Pages '08 as well.

1. Select a heading in your document
2. Open the Inspector (in menu bar click View -> Show Inspector)

   1. Select the Text section
   2. Select the "More" tab
   3. Under "Borders & Rules", click the dropdown that says "none" and select the line you want to use
   4. Below the dropdown select the icon depicting the line above the content
      [image]
3. Open the Styles Drawer (in menu bar click View -> Show Styles Drawer)

   1. Since the text is still selected, the heading you're using should already be highlighted
   2. Click the arrow beside the style
   3. Click "Redefine style from selection"
      [image]

Now everywhere that you used that heading will now have a horizontal line over it, and it will automatically appear whenever you insert new headings.

Comment: @zneak Sure thing, I hope the answer is still useful